# Not remembering if you made and Oath in Allah's name and then breaking it

Tags: sawm

I don't remember whether i made an oath in Allah's name to a friend promising him that i will not tell anyone about a matter of his. It's been two years since that happened and now he tells people about the same matter; however I mentioned the matter to a person now and then i remembered that i might have had an oath. Do i have to fast 3 days?